# Why Email Ext plugin doesn't refresh the value of ${PROJECT_DEFAULT_CONTENT} token?

Tags: groovy, jenkins, email-ext

I defined HTML content in Default Content field embedded with some tokens, and used Pre-Send script to process the evaluated content (by parse/rebuild """${PROJECT_DEFAULT_CONTENT}""" string). But, when I ran the build again, the email body kept the same as previous, even It's pretty changed for sure. So I doubt ${PROJECT_DEFAULT_CONTENT} was not refreshed correctly. Does anyone meet this ever?

Comment: Can you please post the `Content` field where you are using tokens?

Comment: Thanks Technext, deleted TRs and STYLE as below
<html>
<head>
<title>${ENV, var="JOB_NAME"}-#${BUILD_NUMBER} Build Log</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body offset="0">
<table id="maintable" class="reference">
    <tr>
        <td>Passed/Total</td>
        <td>${ROBOT_PASSRATIO}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test Report</td>
        <td>${ROBOT_REPORTLINK}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Failed Cases</td>
        <td style="width: 100%; white-space: nowrap; word-break: keep-all;">${ROBOT_FAILEDCASES}</td></tr>    
</table>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Is there no change at all in the mail body? Are the variables (`BUILD_NUMBER`, `ROBOT_PASSRATIO`, `ROBOT_REPORTLINK` etc.) showing their values?

Comment: no, no change at all, since I processed them like xmlParser.parseText(${PROJECT_DEFAULT_CONTENT}) via pre-send script before sending out, so I guess ${PROJECT_DEFAULT_CONTENT} was not reset/re-fetch correctly so each time I saw the exactly same content as in previous email. Sometime, I can see ${PROJECT_DEFAULT_CONTENT}'s value (means evaluated string) is stored in Pre-Send Script field - that's very odd.......... how can this happen that I can see the actual string value from a history build on Job Configuration page......